# Load javascript function with MongoDB - Java

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb

I have to save a function in system.js collection using java driver.

```
try{
    MongoClient mongoclient = new MongoClient(HOST,PORT);
    DB db = mongoclient.getDB("test");
    System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
    DBCollection jsColl = db.getCollection("system.js");
    DBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("_id","echoFunction").append("value", "function(x) {return x};");
    jsColl.insert(doc); 
    System.out.println("Javascript function saved");
}
```

My code save `echoFunction` in system.js collection in the form of string. I need to call `db.loadServerScripts()` from MongoDB shell to load the javascript code. 
How can I call `db.loadServerScripts()` from my java application?

Comment: did you tried to query echoFunction as well ? . I am facing issues to query this stored procedure using eval

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `system.js` collection is storing Javascript functions for use in MapReduce or queries with the `$where` operator.

What `db.loadServerScripts()` does is load the Javascript sourcecode into the shell so that they can be executed in the shell. That execution happens client-sided inside the mongo shell, not on the database. So the equivalent in Java would be to query `system.js` and then run the returned script sourcecode with Java's own JavaScript engine (Nashorn).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`.

```
BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject(
                "eval",
                "db.loadServerScripts()"
        );
mongoDatabase.runCommand(command);
```

This will allow to run any function in `system.js` from Java by using the same `eval` technique.

BTW you may find issues with how you inserted your JS function in `system.js`. When you insert a function from the shell you actually pass JS code and not a string. I had issues with this so I just did the following nasty trick:

```
String command = String.format("db.system.js.save(" +
        "   {" +
        "     _id: \"%s\"," +
        "     value : %s" +
        "   }" +
        ")", javascriptFunction.getName(), javascriptFunction.getCode());
BasicDBObject evalCommand = new BasicDBObject(
        "eval",
        command
);
```

Comment: eval is depreacted now , what is the alternative for that

Comment: @Anshul I cannot find the command - `db.loadserverscripts()` in my mongo shell, too.